# innerHTML not updating in the UI

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

DOM not being reflection changes when i am assigning the innerHTMl to one of the node.

`const elem: NodeListOf = document.querySelectorAll('.i_input_box_fraction') as NodeListOf;

```
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('add_Border').length) {
      elem.forEach((node, i) => {
        if (node.classList.contains('add_Border')) {
          node.children[0].innerHTML += event;
        }
      });
    } `
```

Comment: yep they are same @nemesv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add your event into variable, which is being used in HTML Eg:

```
if (node.classList.contains('add_Border')) {
   node.children[0].innerHTML += event;
   // update your variable here
   this.answer += event;
}
```